# How to set start index for XAxis?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to display LineChart with values associated with time.

Currently X index for Entries is it's time presentation in minutes for the day (like for value (11.04,14:30) it's X index is 870).

Difference in times in one chart could be small, so i want to set the start position for left side of XAxis - so for first entry with 14:30 time the start position for XAxis could be 14:00 (840 index).

I've tried to do this with `moveViewToX(840)` accompanied with `i.e. setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6*30);` , but XAxis starts from 0 as without that call.

I can modify each Entry's xvalues (i.e. subtract from it's x-value the value of current 'start time') and then use XValueFormatter to display index label properly, but i hope there is another, more handy way. With dynamic data adding it could be not so simple task..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that i haven't read wiki well

> Please note that all methods modifying the viewport need to be called on the Chart after setting data.

setVisibleXRangeMaximum begin to work when I call it after adding Entries to the chart. At first try it was called right after adding only XValues.