# Disable X-axis grouping of columns

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I want the dates on the X-axis to follow without missing dates (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on). When I know exactly how many columns there will be in the chart, I can solve the problem by calling `setScaleMinima(_:scaleY:)`:

[image]

But when I have a large number of dates, with the same scale minima, the dates start to be grouped:

[image]

How can I make do that, regardless of the number of dates, all numbers without grouping are displayed on the X axis?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @aheze I use https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: @aheze So how can i solve my problem? Do you know how to turn off grouping on X axis?

Comment: Sorry... I don't know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `setVisibleXRangeMinimum(minXRange:)` and `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(maxXRange:)` to set the minimum and maximum number of chart columns. But these methods will only take effect if there is data in the chart (thx to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659825/6698055) answer), so for convenience I call them every time the data changes:

```swift
public class MyChartView: BarChartView {
    
    override public var data: ChartData? {
        didSet {
            self.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(2.0)
            self.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(8.0)
        }
    }
}
```